# Change of a basis by a linear map $T : M_{22}(\mathbb{R}) \to P_2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm not sure how to do this question, and more specifically how to interpret the t's in this case. There are 2 parts to the question and i don't understand how to answer either or where to even start.

Consider the linear map $T : M_{22}(\mathbb{R}) \to P_2(\mathbb{R})$ defined as
$$
T(e_{11})=t^2, \quad T(e_{12})=t+t^2, \quad T(e_{21})=-t, \quad T(e_{22})=1,
$$
where
$$
e_{11} = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}, \quad
e_{12} = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}, \quad
e_{21} = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\1 & 0\end{bmatrix}, \quad
e_{22} = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}
$$
are the elements of the standard basis of $M_{22}(\mathbb{R})$.

**Question 1:** Find the value of $T\left( \begin{bmatrix}a_{11} & a_{12} \\a_{21} & a_{22} \end{bmatrix} \right)$.

**Question 2:** Find the matrix of the map $T$ with respect to the standard bases ${e_{11},e_{12},e_{21},e_{22}}$ for $M_{22}(\mathbb{R})$ and ${1,t,t^2}$ for $P_2(\mathbb{R})$.

Sorry if this question is noob, just really stuck right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> First question

it is
$$T(a_{11}e_{11}+a_{12}e_{12}+a_{21}e_{21}+a_{22}e_{22})$$

$$=a_{11}T(e_{11})+a_{12}T(e_{12})+a_{21}T(e_{21})+a_{22}T(e_{22})$$

$$=a_{11}t^2+a_{12}(t+t^2)-a_{21}t+a_{22}$$

$$=(a_{11}+a_{12})t^2+(a_{12}-a_{21})t+a_{22}.$$

> Second question

the matrix  of $T$ is

$$\begin{bmatrix} 0&0&0&1\\
0&1&-1&0\\1&1&0&0 \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Could you explain how did you get to the second answer?

Comment: The first colum is $T(e_{11})$ expressed in $1,t,t^2$. the same for the others.